# Reading a text file in my .jar

Tags: java, io, inputstream, bufferedreader

Lets say I'm making a program that needs to copy all the lines in a .txt file within my .jar file. it is in the package `program.files` and it is named text.txt. I've been looking all over the internet, and i cant find what I'm looking for. i think that this idea:

```
public String readSpecificFromJar(String dir, int line) {
    String read = null;
    try {
        InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream(dir);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(in));

        /**
         * declare string variable and prime the read
         */
        read = bufferedReader.readLine();

        for (int i = 1; i < line; i++) {
            read = bufferedReader.readLine();
        }

        bufferedReader.close();
    } catch (IOException ioexception) {
        Dialogs.fail("Could not read txt file from the JAR!!! Error Code: 06");
    }

    return read;
}
```

would work, but i tried that and it gave me all kinds of errors. what i think the problem would be is declaring the `InputStream in` the way it does it want the file to be right there with the Main method. how would i change this so it is not the case? thanks in advance!

EDIT:
due to some confusion, i want to clear this up. for the String `dir` i am entering `files/text.txt`. it wont work. how do i fix this?

EDIT 2:
OK i feel like the problem isn't getting across, and I'm kinda getting aggravated, mainly because I'm pretty tired. the code that WORKS for a different program is up above, where the `dir` is simply `"text.txt"`

THIS DOESN'T WORK FOR WHAT I'M DOING AND IM NOT SURE WHY. again, the file is IN THE CLASSPATH so `dir` is only `"text.txt"`. I want my .txt file to be `"files/text.txt"`. How do i do this?

EDIT 3:
I dont know if i mentioned it, but my .txt file is INSIDE my jar. just to clear up the confusion. so really, the path of the .jar file shouldn't matter, as in I shouldn't have to type it in with the `dir`. also, the main class is in the package `main` and the .txt file is in the package `files` all within the same program named `copy`. also, i tried moving the txt file to the same package as the `main` class, also didn't work.

EDIT 4:
by the way, the package that holds the method for reading from the jar is `IO`. as in the class `io` is inside the package `IO`. all of my files such as images and txt are in the package `files`. just thought id clear that up. i tried moving the txt file to the package of the `io` class, and that worked, but if its in any other package, even if i include the package name in the `dir` it wont work. any ideas as to why?

Comment: The .txt file needs to be in the CLASSPATH.  Does your JAR file have a manifest?  It should.  Add the path to the .txt file into the CLASSPATH and it should work just fine.

Comment: Better add the character encoding of the text.txt, for instance `new InputStreamReader(in, "Windows-1252")`. So on other OS's and countries everything goes okay. `readLine()` yields null at end-of-file, otherwise the line _without_ line endings. So do `read += br.readLine() + "\n";` or so.

Comment: try passing in "program/files/text.txt" as "dir", since that's the package name

Comment: good idea, but it didnt work :(

Comment: Did you try to make the dir absolute like "/program/files/test.txt"?

Comment: i did not, so ill try that now

Comment: that worked along with the first answer! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>The `.txt` file should be in</strike> The root directory of `dir` is **the same directory where your class file is located in.**

---

> EDIT: due to some confusion, i want to clear this up. for the String
>   dir i am entering files/text.txt. it wont work. how do i fix this?

What is the path of the class? (the class that contains readSpecificFromJar()) If the `.class` file and the `.txt` file are both in the same directory, then you should make it like this:

```
dir = "text.txt";
```

---

> EDIT 4: by the way, the package that holds the method for reading from
>   the jar is IO. as in the class io is inside the package IO. all of my
>   files such as images and txt are in the package files. just thought id
>   clear that up. i tried moving the txt file to the package of the io
>   class, and that worked, but if its in any other package, even if i
>   include the package name in the dir it wont work. any ideas as to why?

Try this:

```
dir = "../files/text.txt";
```

I believe this would work if your structure is as follows:

```
   javaApp.jar
        |
   _____|_____
  |           |
files         IO
  |           |
  |           |
text.txt   io.class
```

Comment: @wbAnon See the last part of my answer :)